# How to associate Radio Button value with Input Field

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a quiz application...

I have created a question text area, and a number of input fields for options..

Each input field has a radio button, if user clicks it, it will consider the associated input field as correct answer..

[image]

I have created some input fields and radio button with each input field

```
<div id="items">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="options[]" required /> Is Correct: <input type="radio" name="is_correct" value="yes"/> <br><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="options[]" required /> Is Correct: <input type="radio" name="is_correct" value="yes"/>
</div>
```

when i Submit this form it stores `yes` with each Option. I am unable to understand how to store the value of only 1 input field.

Kindly guide me 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you get value of options is input1 answer is  input1 or if options value is input2 answer is input2

```
<input type="radio" name="options" value="input1">Is Correct<br>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="input2">Is Correct
```

> input1 is name of textbox 1
>
> input2 is name of textbox 2

Get value on form post :-

```
$nam=$_POST['options'];
$answer=$_POST[$nam];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use input as below :

```
<div id="items">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="options[]" required /> Is Correct: <input type="radio" name="is_correct[]" value="yes"/> <br><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="options[]" required /> Is Correct: <input type="radio" name="is_correct[]" value="yes"/>
</div>
```